# phpmyadmin http 500 error.. No such file or directory in /usr/share/php/Symfony/Component/Cache/autoload.php on line 6

Tags: php, phpmyadmin

here is apache2 error log;

> [proxy_fcgi:error] [pid 8457] [client 192.168.2.10:63922] AH01071: Got error 'PHP message: PHP Warning:  require_once(Symfony/Polyfill/Apcu/autoload.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /usr/share/php/Symfony/Component/Cache/autoload.php on line 6
> PHP message: PHP Fatal error:  require_once(): Failed opening required 'Symfony/Polyfill/Apcu/autoload.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/php') in /usr/share/php/Symfony/Component/Cache/autoload.php on line 6'

how can I solve this?

Comment: This kind of errors are often shown when `composer install` hasn't ran, could you try running the command?

Comment: yes I ran the command. here is the result : Continue as root/super user [yes]? yes
Installing dependencies from lock file (including require-dev)
Verifying lock file contents can be installed on current platform.
Nothing to install, update or remove
Generating autoload files
1 package you are using is looking for funding.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found a fix for Ubuntu 18.04. I downgraded the package **php-symfony-polyfill-apcu** back to `1.6.0-2`. Apparently, the version that was upgraded no longer includes all the same files, including the `'Symfony/Polyfill/Apcu/autoload.php'` file, that is causing the issue here.

Comment: wow super but I don't know how to downgrade?

Comment: sudo apt install php-symfony-polyfill-apcu=1.6.0-2

Comment: E: Unable to locate package php-symfony-polyfill-apcu

Answer (score 1):

you need to downgraded the package php-symfony-polyfill-apcu

```
sudo apt install php-symfony-polyfill-apcu=1.6.0-2
sudo service apache2 restart
```

Comment: E: Unable to locate package php-symfony-polyfill-apcu